# How can i transfer ArrayList between Activities?

Tags: android, android-intent, arraylist, parcelable

I'm trying to transfer `ArrayList` between activities, but nothing I've tried works as well.
This was my best shot, but this didn't work either.

I'm calling the external action here:

```
getComics getComicInfo = new getComics(charName, pageNum);
getComicInfo.execute();
getIntentData()
```

and here i'm trying to put data, but the problem is due the fact that this is an external action, so I can't shift through activits.

```
    if(counter == comicInfoObject.length()){

        Log.v("check arr length =>" , Integer.toString(comicList.size()));
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra("comicArrayList", (ArrayList<Comics>)comicList);
        }
```

and here i'm tring to retrive the data, but it doesn't get inside the "if"

```
public void getIntentData(){
        Intent i = getIntent();
        if(i != null && i.hasExtra("comicArrayList")){
            comicList2 = i.getParcelableExtra("comicArrayList");
            int size = comicList2.size();
        }
    }
```

first code is where I call an external class that using api and in the bottom line creates the arrayList
     second code is inside the external class, where I'm trying to pass the arrayList with putExtra
     third code is where i'm tring to retrive the data after getIntentData().

Comment: How do you start the other activity?

Comment: i've edited, missed copyed stuff and explained.

Comment: Dont use Parcelable, use Serializeable.

Comment: I am not on a PC  try seaeching the web about Serializable  vs. Parcelable.

Comment: Please post your `Comics` class. Unless it is very large and complicated there is no reason why you cannot use `Parcelable`. `Parcelable` is something you need to learn to use if you are going to be doing any significant Android programming.

Comment: @Aviv1002 i wrote this link: http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/ it is a comprehensive guide for this issue, but unfortunately someone deleted my post.

Answer (score 0):

Pack at the sender `Activity`

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(<KEY>, ArrayList<Comics extends Parcelable> list);
startActivity(intent);
```

Extract at the receiver `Activity`

```
getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra(<KEY>);
```

Comment: where do I place those? it doesn't allow me to use extends Parcelable neither start activity

Comment: Extend your custom `ArrayList` class to `Parceable`

Comment: Intent i = new Intent();
   Intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("comicArrayList", ArrayList<Comics extends Parcelable> comicList);
   startActivity(i);  tried this, isn't working, problems with the extends.

Comment: You should extend `Parceable` while defining Comics class. class Comics extends Parceable {}

Comment: It doesn't allow me to use extends Parceable, but it allow me to use implements Parcelable.

Comment: My bad, Yes, Parceable is an interface. use `implements` instead

Comment: Well still getting error in this line: i.putParcelableArrayListExtra("comicArrayList", comicList<Comics extends Parcelable> comicList);  can't extends (calling "syntax error)

Comment: Just pass the Comics list in second parameter of putParceableArrayListExtra

Comment: @Aviv1002 i wrote this link: http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/ it is a comprehensive guide for this issue, but unfortunately someone deleted my post.

Answer (score 0):

You need make a Comics class that implements `Parcelable`, then use `put ParcelableArrayListExtra`to pass arraylist.

Here is a sample link for [Pass data between activities](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-parcelable-example-passing-data-between-activities/) implements Parcelable

However be careful if your array list too big, you could get intent exception, for this case you could think about a `static reference` to store your array list.

Comment: Dont use Parcelable, use Serializeable.

Comment: Parcelable is faster than Serializeable, and serialization is an expensive operation you must keep it minimum. And also Serializable is a standard Java interface, Parcelable is an Android specific interface

Comment: No is it not, Parcelable is expensive too and is very hard to understand, Serializeable is easy and fast enough.

Comment: @ErdincAy I had an hard time with the Parcelable and didn't succed in the end, mind giving me some guide about Serializeable?